# How can I build a pip package and import the package from the directory at the same time?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools

I am working in a mono repo. The simplified directory structure looks like this:

```
.
|-- lib
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- package1
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- package1
|   |   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |   `-- module.py
|   |   `-- setup.py
|   `-- package2
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- module.py
`-- script.py
```

We recently decided to publish our libraries, for example package1, to an internal repository. To achieve this I moved *module.py* from `lib.package1` to `lib.package1.package1` and added a *setup.py* to `lib.package1`. The problem is that we have many script which we call like `python3 script.py` that import libraries like `from lib.package1 import module`.

I want to do two things at the same time:

1. make `package1` buildable with setuptools and importable like
   `import package1` after pip installation from whichever machine and location
2. let my scripts which still use a rpm based packaging approach import the packages as usual from the *lib* dir like `from lib.package1 import module`

I've read the python documentation on the import system and how to write *setup.py* scripts. Based on the documentation I experimented with my *setup.py* and my *_*init*_.py* files. However I cannot figure out a way to achieve both things from the same git repo. Is that possible?